JavaScript - export HTML to Word not including images
I'm trying to export an HTML element that includes images to a Word doc using the below function I've put together using various online sources. The Word document download is triggered, but the 1st download does not include the images. The 2nd time and every time after the download is triggered, it includes the images.
Has anyone come across this issue before? Is there anything wrong with my exportToDoc function?
export function exportToDoc(element, filename = "") {
  let html =
    "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office'" +
    " xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'><head><meta><title>Export HTML To Doc</title></head><body>";
  let footer = "</body></html>";
  html = html + document.getElementById(element).innerHTML + footer;

  var statiC = {
    mhtml: {
      top:
      /* eslint-disable */
        "Mime-Version: 1.0\nContent-Base: " +
        location.href +
        '\nContent-Type: Multipart/related; boundary="NEXT.ITEM-BOUNDARY";type="text/html"\n\n--NEXT.ITEM-BOUNDARY\nContent-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"\nContent-Location: ' +
        location.href +
        "\n\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n_html_</html>",
      head: '<head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">\n<style>\n_styles_\n</style>\n</head>\n',
      body: "<body>_body_</body>",
    },
  };

  var css =
    "<style>" +
    "img {width:auto; height: 800px, margin-right: 100px}" +
    "</style>";

  //  Image Area %%%%
  var options = { maxWidth: 500 };
  var images = Array();
  var img = document.querySelectorAll("#" + element)[0].querySelectorAll("img");
  for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    // Calculate dimensions of output image
    var w = Math.min(img[i].width, options.maxWidth);
    var h = img[i].height * (w / img[i].width);
    // Create canvas for converting image to data URL
    var canvas = document.createElement("CANVAS");
    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;
    // Draw image to canvas
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.drawImage(img[i], 0, 0, w, h);
    // Get data URL encoding of image
    var uri = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    // document.querySelectorAll(img[i])[0].attr("src", img[i].src);
    img[i].src = img[i].src;
    img[i].width = w;
    img[i].height = h;
    // Save encoded image to array
    images[i] = {
      type: uri.substring(uri.indexOf(":") + 1, uri.indexOf(";")),
      encoding: uri.substring(uri.indexOf(";") + 1, uri.indexOf(",")),
      location: img[i].src,
      data: uri.substring(uri.indexOf(",") + 1),
    };
  }

  // Prepare bottom of mhtml file with image data
  var imgMetaData = "\n";
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    imgMetaData += "--NEXT.ITEM-BOUNDARY\n";
    imgMetaData += "Content-Location: " + images[i].location + "\n";
    imgMetaData += "Content-Type: " + images[i].type + "\n";
    imgMetaData += "Content-Transfer-Encoding: " + images[i].encoding + "\n\n";
    imgMetaData += images[i].data + "\n\n";
  }
  imgMetaData += "--NEXT.ITEM-BOUNDARY--";
  // end Image Area %%

  const output = statiC.mhtml.top.replace("_html_", statiC.mhtml.head.replace("_styles_", css) + html) + imgMetaData;
  const url = "data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(output);

  //file name
  filename = filename ? filename + ".doc" : "document.doc";

  // Creates the  download link element dynamically
  let downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

  //Link to the file
  downloadLink.href = url;

  //Setting up file name
  downloadLink.download = filename;

  //triggering the function
  downloadLink.click();
  
  //Remove the a tag after download starts.
  document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
}

The element being exported just contain some basic div, p, and img tags

Are you ensuring the browser has fully loaded the images before the function is run?

yes! Images are hosted locally so theres not much latency. I even tried adding some 2 to 5 second timeouts around the code for testing but I get the same result.
